# Java Quiz System, help required in changing the name of a node

Tags: java, swing, tree

Here's the problem: 
I have three Classes. One is a DynamicTree, one is called "main application" which all other classes MUST pass through. The  other is called "addQForm" which is basically a form to add a node to the Dynamic Tree.

So in my Dynamic Tree there is a group of functions which add a node to the tree. These are as follows.

```
public DefaultMutableTreeNode addObject(Object child) {
  DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode = null;
  TreePath parentPath = tree.getSelectionPath();
  if (parentPath == null) {
      parentNode = rootNode;
      } 
  else {
          parentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (parentPath.getLastPathComponent());
}

  return addObject(parentNode, child, true);
}



public DefaultMutableTreeNode addObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, Object child) {
     return addObject(parent, child, false);
}



public DefaultMutableTreeNode addObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, Object child, boolean shouldBeVisible) {

       DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(child);


    if (parent == null) {
       parent = rootNode;
    }

    treeModel.insertNodeInto(childNode, parent, parent.getChildCount());



    if (shouldBeVisible) {
       tree.scrollPathToVisible(new TreePath(childNode.getPath()));
   }
return childNode;
    }
```

Okay so from here, I have the mainApplication which creates a GUI and adds the Dynamic Tree to it.

```
treePanel = new DynamicTree();
populateTree(treePanel);
```

So the Main Application has a button which has the following code:

```
if (ADD_COMMAND.equals(command)) {
        //Add button clicked
        addQForm.main(null);
        treePanel.addObject(" New Node" + newNodeSuffix);
```

The Main Application also has the function "add Node" which shows a message dialogue (just to check what is stored in the local variable qTitle).
It then calls the "add Object Function" from the Dynamic Tree.

```
public void addNode(String qTitle){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, qTitle, "Error Message",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    treePanel.addObject(qTitle);

}
```

So in my third class I have a Text Field and a Button. When The button is clicked the text is extracted from the text field and the form is closed.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    PrintWriter out;
    try {
        qTitle = qtitle.getText();
        out = new PrintWriter(qtitle.getText() + ".txt");
        out.println(qtitle.getText());
        out.println(q.getText());
        out.println(sUnit);
        out.close();
        dispose();


        MainApplication mainapplication = new MainApplication();
        mainapplication.addNode(qTitle);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

As you can see I called the function addNode from the main application by instantiating.

BUT the variable is passed through to Main Application as it should however the second line:

```
treePanel.addObject(qTitle);
```

Will not function. I have attempted accessing other methods within my Dynamic Tree Class so this is just one example.

Can someone please explain to me why it refuses to complete this line of code?
I figured the error is when I instantiate but I'm not sure why...

Comment: The only code well formatted above is your last `actionPerformed` method, but all the others -- not so much. Please take the time and trouble to fix your posted code's formatting. If formatted well, your code is much easier to read and understand.

Comment: Sorry about this, I'm quite messy but I'll be sure to edit it properly next time. Do you know why this happens? I'm having the same problem when I've made other functions. It works perfectly in the mainapplication when I call a function from the DynamicTree class however when I am using the AddQuestionForm function and call a function in the mainapplication class to call the DynamicTree Class it just won't work...

Comment: 1. You may want to edit your question and improve the format of your code *this* time and not *next* time as many/most of us won't bother looking at code if the poster makes it hard to read. 2. Consider creating and posting a valid [mcve] that illustrates your problem for us.